# Discrete random variable( how to make the table)

Tags: probability

A company makes computer.one out of every 50 computer is faulty, but the company doesn't know which one are faulty until a buyer complains.The company makes a 100 dollar as a profit on the sale of any working computer,but suffer a loss of 177 dollar for every faulty computer because they have to repair the unit.Let X be the profit, write 
the probability distribution table and check whether the company can expect a profit in the long term.

I don't know how to construct the table

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Could you perhaps add more context to your question, such as what you have tried or what difficulties you have encountered?

Comment: Quote:".one out of every computer is faulty"  What does this mean ? Have you omitted something ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the table is made up of the values $X$ can take and their probabilities?

And that the expected value is these probabilities multiplied with their respective values.

From your rather vague question the only thing one can conclude is

$$E[X] = \frac{49}{50} \cdot \$100 + \frac{1}{50} \cdot (-\$177)$$

From here i assume you can construct the table.